# Dynamic charts or graphs in PDF

Tags: xml, pdf, flash, interactive

I want to embed dynamic charts or graphs in PDF which should have facility to sort, drill down, group by, expand collapse etc. One option I am thinking of is to create dynamic charts in Flash SWF from XML file & then embed this SWF as well as XML file in PDF. I understand that we can embed SWF in PDF using iText. However how to embed SWF & XML at the same time in PDF. Will this work? My other question is if there are any options other than SWF+XML combo which I can use to create PDFs with dynamic charts or graphs available for free or low cost. Is this possible with JasperReports or BIRT or Pentaho or FusionCharts? Can I embed dyanamic FusionCharts in PDF?

Thanks,

Wap Rau

Comment: It is possible to both with iText and RenderX, these are the two tools I use most. And you can embed just about any interactive Flash content. I use Anychart but Fusionchart also works. I can post code for you in a bit. Have to dig it out.

Answer (score 1):

One note: Be aware that Richmedia in PDF is PDF 1.7 with extensions and hence only works with Adobe Reader 9+ (10 not recommended as it has a bug in this feature that was never fixed).

First answer is using RenderX, as I work for RenderX this one is easy. Here's a template XSL that can be used to insert what is known as a RichMedia Annotation.

You may have some XML in a file like this:

```
 <chart swf="SWF\Anychart.swf" flashvar="XMLData" width="300" height="300">
    <anychart>....</anychart> <!-- put the XML for the chart here -->
    <resources>
       <resource src="img\a.png"/>
    </resources>
  </chart>
```

You can get from these to call the template below.

The parameters here are:

chartxml: the XML file that drives the chart

width and height: self explanatory

flashvar: the FlashVar command to pass the XML to the SWF. For Anychart this is "XMLData" for Fusioncharts this is "dataXML"

@swf: in this template this is the path to the actual SWF file (like 
"SWF'Anychart.swf" or "SWF\Bar2D.swf"

resource: any other external resource needed by the chart or map or whatever (like images)

```
<xsl:template name="add-on.richmedia">
    <xsl:param name="chartxml"/>
    <xsl:param name="width"/>
    <xsl:param name="height"/>
    <xsl:param name="flashvar"/>
    <fo:block>
        <rx:rich-media-object scaling="non-uniform" name="test" width="{concat($width,'pt')}" height="{concat($height,'pt')}" content-width="scale-to-fit" content-height="scale-to-fit" transparency="true">
            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                <xsl:value-of select="@swf"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
                <rx:flash-var name="{$flashvar}" content="true">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="$chartxml" mode="copy-of"/>
                </rx:flash-var>
            <xsl:for-each select="resources/resource">
                <rx:rich-media-resource>
                    <xsl:attribute name="src">
                        <xsl:text>url('</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@src"/>
                        <xsl:text>')</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@src"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </rx:rich-media-resource>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </rx:rich-media-object>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

This would insert a block into your FO document with a rx:rich-media-object. RenderX handles all the internals of linking the associated assets (the chart XML and any resources) inside the PDF. The result is an interactive Flash chart inside the document when formatted to PDF. There are also other ways to do this. You can even insert the flash and use "XMLfile" (for Anychart) or "dataurl" for FUsioncharts and put in a URL to the data (like http://mychartserver.com/getdata) or whatever and feed dynamic data to the PDF every time it is open.

For iText, there are perfect samples right on their site instead of posting more here. Look at this link, it shows all the code in Java required to insert a SWF and data set:

http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=300